# parse text in nested html tags for inline editing

Tags: php, jquery, html, parsing, dom

After doing a search for my query i'm posting this question here...
I'm working on inline editing script... 
I want to get the text between any html tag onclick on a modal box with save and cancel options so that it can be edited... These values are also sent to database using php script

I have used jquery `.text` & `.html` functions to get the value of tags of format

```
<p>Some text</p>
```

but i'm not able to edit the value when the format is like

```
<p>This is a <a href="#">Sample</a> <b>text</b></p>
```

My Jquery Code is:

```
$("#diag-wrap").hide();
        $("span,p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,li,a").click(function(){
            $(this).addClass('edit');
            ss = $('.edit').text();
            //alert(ss);
            $("#diag-wrap").show();
            $("#show").html('<textarea id="test" cols="50" rows="15">'+ss+'</textarea>');       
            $("#test").htmlarea();
        });//click end


    $("#save").click(function(){
        var edited = $("#test").val();
        //alert(edited);
        $.post("bounce-back.php",{
            edited:edited, 
            old:ss}, function(data,success){
            //alert(data);
            $('.edit').html(data);
            $('*').removeClass('edit');
            $("#diag-wrap").hide();
            });
    });

    $("#cancel").click(function(){
            $('*').removeClass('edit');
            $("#diag-wrap").hide();
    });
```

Code in bounce-back.php

```
$old_val= $_POST['old'];
echo $edited_val= $_POST['edited'];
$qur= mysql_query("insert into edit (old, new) values('$old_val', '$edited_val')");
```

This is the HTML popup code, if it helps anyhow...

`<div id="diag-wrap" style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#999; opacity:0.7; top:0px;">
    <div id="wrap" style="width:500px; height:500px; margin:auto;">
        <div id="show" style="width:419px; border:2px solid #000; background-color:#FFF;"> </div>
        <button id="save">Save</button><button id="cancel">Cancel</button>
    </div>
    </div>`

Please help me out in finding a feasible solution...

Comment: I would look at leveraging an existing rich text editor component. TinyMCE or CKEditor are a couple of good places to start. If you continue down the path you are on the rabbit hole is going to get really deep.. there is a whole boatload of corner cases you have to deal with if you are developing a richtext editor.

Comment: put code in question properly formatted please

Comment: @GordonM Sir this is just one part of the module that i have mentioned...the complete objective is to load any web page and edit any of its textual content...

Comment: Your PHP script is wide open to an SQL injection attack.  At the very least you should apply mysql_real_escape_string() to the input.

Comment: Wouldn't the simplest way to do this be to use a regex that matches everything not between triangular brackets ('<' and '>') and present each of those components to the user as a distinct textbox to edit? So in your example case you'd use a regex that returns you the array `['This is a ', 'Sample', 'text']` and then you'd create three textboxes, one for editing each of those bits of text? You'll need to figure out how to cleanly deal with whitespace-only bits of text, but other than that all should be well? BTW, you need to properly HTML-escape and SQL-escape the modified text from the user.

Comment: @MarkAmery will you please help me writing the correct regex for parsing such a string, if u think this might be a good solution...as i am not well versed with writing regex...